# Автоматизация выгрузки видео хостинга в ipfs

Tags: javascript, python, c++, linux

Хотелось бы определить основные черты программы способной автоматически  выгружать  гигантский виде архив например из YouTube в ipfs

Comment: RabbitMQ + aiohttp + youtube-dl = профит.

Comment: bash+youtube-dl тоже сработает.

Comment: @Sheridan вот это мне больше нравится)))

Answer (score 0):

Тут, в принципе, должно быть всё просто. Вот необходимый минимум:

1. youtube-dl - оно выкачивает видео.
2. "БД" со списком "что качать". Тут либо список роликов, либо список плейлистов, либо список каналов, либо всё вместе. "БД" - то что вам удобнее. Оракл или текстовый файлик - неважно в данном контексте.

Алгоритм такой:

1. Берем из списка очередной нескачанный
2. Качаем
3. Проверяем. Если не ок - в п.2.
4. Устанавливаем в "БД" признак "скачано"
5. Идём обратно в п.1.

Язык, "БД" - неважно какие. Выбирайте то что кажется подходящим для вас. Я бы взял perl+sqlite.

Comment: Замечательно. Но как бы реализовать автоматическую генерацию списка для скачивания или что то типа того, что бы скрипт сам выгружал последовательно весь ютубе в автономном режиме

Comment: )))))) вотсмотрю краем глаза квн какойто новый - несмешно) а тут прям огонь....) вы бы ещё интернет весь скачали)